# Runtime Error: An exception occurred while executing the custom error page

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, custom-error-pages, custom-errors

I am trying to set up custom errors using IIS for a .net framework application (built using Visual Studio 2015 if that's relevant.)  Our server is a windows server 2012 R2. I have viewed other stack overflow solutions to this issue but none have resolved it. I have custom errors set to on in my web config and in the server managers feature settings. The path to the custom error page (is a static html page) is set in the server manager for all error status codes. Some previous stacks suggested disabling python so I tried that, but it did not resolve anything. My web config looks like:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--other web config-->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false"/>
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0"/>
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false"/>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
    <customErrors defaultRedirect="/Views/Home/customError.cshtml" mode="On"/>
    <compilation debug="true"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <!--<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
      <remove statusCode="500" subStatusCode="-1" />
      <error statusCode="500" subStatusCode="-1" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/Views/Home/customError.cshtml" />
    </httpErrors>-->
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Entities" connectionString="***" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v12.0"/>
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

I didn't see any duplicate static content in the web config. I added all the iis error page redirects directly in the server manager for the application.

When I run the application locally and try to trigger a 404 error, I get the runtime error: An exception occurred while processing your request. Additionally, another exception occurred while executing the custom error page for the first exception. The request has been terminated. 
When I run it via the server(also trying to trigger a 404 error), it loads to the previous page.

I am unsure how to go about resolving this. Any insight would be awesome! Thank you!

Relevant part of the controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;
using BE.Models;
using BE.ViewModels;

namespace BE.Controllers
{

    public class HomeController : Controller
    {

        private Entities db = new Entities();

        // Uri Route: "~/Home"
        // View Route: "/Views/Home/Index.cshtml"
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }


        // Route: "~/Home/customError"
        // View Route: "/Views/Home/customError.cshtml"
        public ActionResult customError()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult About()
        {
            return View();
        }


        public ActionResult Contact()
        {
            return View();
        }



        public ActionResult Resources()
        {
            return View();
        }

    }
}
```

I also modified the global.asax.cs to look like:

```
namespace BE
{
    public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        }
        RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute(
        "Default",
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
         new { 
             controller = "Home", 
             action = "Index", 
             id = UrlParameter.Optional
        }
    );
    };
};
```

However, this gives me build errors.

Comment: You're pointing to a `.cshtml` file instead of a proper HTML file. Perhaps that is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MVC it is ok to redirect to the route that will serve the page. This is usally denoted by the controller, not the view. Unless the view is a static html page. As you are using `.cshtml` I assume you are serving the content from an MVC controller. Your section should look something like the following:

```
<system.web>
    <!-- Default redirect to the ErrorController index -->
    <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Error">
        <!-- Add any custom methods if you want for other error codes -->
        <error redirect="~/Error/NotFound" statusCode="404" />
    </customErrors>
</system.web>
```

Also note the use of the `~/` to denote that the path is relative from the app root.

So ensure in your controllers folder there is a class something like:

```
public class ErrorController : Controller {
    // Uri Route: "~/Error"
    // View Route: "/Views/Error/Index.cshtml"
    public ActionResult Index() {
        return View();
    }

    // Route: "~/Error/NotFound"
    // View Route: "/Views/Error/NotFound.cshtml"
    public ActionResult NotFound() {
        return View();
    }
}
```

In the `Global.asx.cs` or where ever the routes are registered in the `App_Start` folder, there should be a route mapping like this:

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
     new { 
         controller = "Home", 
         action = "Index", 
         id = UrlParameter.Optional 
     }
);
```

This should match your given routes to the right controller.

Comment: So to clarify, I need to put that in my web.config, and the default redirect should lead to the controller, not to the view?

Comment: I just modified the web.config to look like this: <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Controllers/HomeController.cs">
      <!-- Add any custom methods if you want for other error codes -->
      <error redirect="~/Controllers/HomeController.cs/customError.cshtml" statusCode="404" />
    </customErrors> Is that what you had in mind? In running that, I recieved the same error as I had previously.

Comment: That's it. You will only need the `customErrors` part of my answer don't remove the good stuff you already have in the `system.web` section. Then make sure you have a controller to serve the right view. Also ensure that the app routes configuration has something like `"{controller}/{action}/{id}"` so that the route is mapped to the controller correctly.

Comment: <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Controllers/">
      <!-- Add any custom methods if you want for other error codes -->
      <error redirect="~/Controllers/HomeController/customError" statusCode="404" />
    </customErrors> I also tried this which also recieved the same error

Comment: The controller called `HomeController` maps to a controller route `/Home` the app will drop the controller name. The next part of the route is the method. So, `Home/Get` will map to the `HomeController`'s `Get()` method.

Comment: What do you mean by the app roots configuration? Do you mean the default redirect or error redirect, or is a configuration somewhere else entirely. I am also a little confused by the {controller}/{action}/{id}. What do you mean by this? I am editing the post to show the relevant parts of the controller.

Comment: Okay, I got an actual 404 error this time. I am going to update the post with the full controller for context. Thank you so much for your help btw!

Comment: No worries. Don't forget to accept the answer if you found it useful :) .

Comment: I am definitely going to haha, just trying to get it to work first? I updated the post to show the changes to the controller and global.asax.cs by the way

Comment: I am getting build errors on a basically all of the changes to the global.asax file

Comment: Have added the type to the routes... hopefully this is already being done somewhere in your app setup. Sorry, yes that wouldn't have compiled, hard to see without seeing your whole code base.

Comment: I am getting that, RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute, controller, action, and id all do not exist in the current context. Am i missing something. Will edit post to reflect most recent changes. I really appreciate the help, I've been working on this for like 2 days

Comment: Take a look here `RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);` that's the place where these routes are setup :) . Where you have placed that code is invalid. But inside the `RegisterRoutes` method you should see what I'm talking about.

Comment: So I need to put all of the code: RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute(
            "Error",
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
             new
             {
                 controller = "Home",
                 action = "customError",
                 id = UrlParameter.Optional
             }
            );          inside the registerRoutes method? Like inside its parenthesis?

Comment: because that made the whole thing covered in red squigglys

Comment: `.MapRoute("Error", "Error", new { controller = "Home", action = "customError", id = UrlParameter.Optional } );` The second parameter is the URI route as specified in the `web.config` the other properties say which controller and action. I would have a separate controller for your errors though, as I have shown in my answer. The default route should work then.

Comment: Okay I think that works? I am getting a 404 error, but it's on the files specifiec in my web.config. (ie.<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Controllers/HomeController.cs">
      <!-- Add any custom methods if you want for other error codes -->
      <error redirect="~/Controllers/HomeController/customError.cshtml‌​" statusCode="404" />
    </customErrors>0

Comment: Requested URL    http://localhost:57292/Controllers/HomeController.cs/customError.cshtml‌​?aspxerrorpath=/ah
Physical Path    C:\Users\663255\Documents\be\BE\Controllers\HomeController.cs\customError.cshtml‌​

Comment: It doesn't like the above paths

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149152/discussion-between-cassie-h-and-tigerswithguitars).